# What Overcharge Capacity means in Borderlands

Tags: borderlands

Certain Shields in Borderlands have "Overcharge Capacity" as their special power. What exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [Borderlands Wikia](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Shield#Special_Effects), it's just a modifier name that means the capacity of the shield is greatly increased over the default (by +60%), but with a slight recharge delay (by +10%).

The weaker versions of this modifier are "High Capacity" and "Very High Capacity".